# Search for exe file within a condition

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint

I want to search for all .exe files greater than 200 kB or smaller than 120 kB in the current folder and its subfolders. Then I want to move them to another folder called "folder" and execute in this folder the file called "executable.exe" infinitely and show some information about its memory consumption.

Any ideas?

I'm using Linux Mint. I used the find command to search for ".exe" files, per [Indrek's answer](https://superuser.com/a/429860).

```
find . -name "*.exe" \( -size +200k -o -size -120k \)
```

Now what I want to do is to move those file to another folder called "myFolder", and after this I have to execute any file in this folder called "MyExec.exe"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: since you specified that you're using Linux, most of the options I originally described are irrelevant, except for the `find` command:

```
find . -name "*.exe" \( -size +200k -o -size -120k \)
```

To move all matching files to another directory, you have several options.

1. Use the `-exec` argument, which (as the name suggests) allows you to execute a given command for each matched file. See [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for more information.

   ```
   find . -name "*.exe" \( -size +200k -o -size -120k \) -exec mv {} ./myFolder \;
   ```

   Here, `{}` is replaced with the name of each file as it's processed. See also [`man mv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) for information on that command.
2. Alternatively, wrap the entire `find` command in backticks and pass it as the first argument to `mv`:

   ```
   mv `find . -name "*.exe" \( -size +200k -o -size -120k \)` ./myFolder
   ```
3. You can also accomplish the same thing by piping the output of the `find` command to `xargs`:

   ```
   find . -name "*.exe" \( -size +200k -o -size -120k \) | xargs -i mv {} ./myFolder
   ```

Once again, `{}` is replaced with the current filename. See [`man xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) for more information.

Finally, to execute `MyExec.exe` (I'm assuming you're using Wine for this):

```
wine ./myFolder/MyExec.exe
```

I'll preserve my original answer below, in case someone needs to do something similar on Windows.

---

There's several options, depending on how you want to execute your search.

1. Since you mention .exe files, I'm assuming you're on Windows. The first option would be using the search box in Windows Explorer. Just navigate to the folder where you want to start your search, hit <kbd>F3</kbd> and enter the following search query:

   ```
   *.exe (Size:<120kB OR Size:>200kB)
   ```

   For more information, see [Advanced tips for searching in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows).

   To move the files, simply select them and drag&drop (or cut&paste) them to the target folder.
2. If you want to do this from the command line (for instance, if the process needs to be automated):

   ```
   forfiles /m *.exe /s /c "cmd /c if @fsize GTR 204800 (echo @path) else if @fsize LSS 122880 (echo @path)"
   ```

   For more information, see the documentation for the [`forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) and [`if`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) commands.

   To move the files, replace `echo @path` with `move @path C:\destination\folder`.
3. Alternatively, Powershell provides a cleaner syntax:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".exe" -and ( $_.Length -gt 204800 -or $_.Length -lt 122880 ) }
   ```

   For more information, see the documentation on the [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347686.aspx) and [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315399.aspx) cmdlets. Note the file sizes are in bytes (204800 B = 200 kB, and 122880 B = 120 kB).

   To move the files, pipe the output of the above to the [Move-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315310.aspx) cmdlet.
4. Finally, if you have Cygwin or some other Unix-compatible shell available (which I assume you do, from the "bash" tag), you can also use the `find` command:

   ```
   find . -name "*.exe" \( -size +200k -o -size -120k \)
   ```

   For more information, see [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

   To move the files, use the `-exec` argument.

As for the second part of your question, maybe you could elaborate what you're trying to achieve with executing "executable.exe" and how it relates to the finding and moving of other .exe files.

Comment: Thank you, I used the 4th solution. can you see my EDIT !!

Comment: @dotNET I updated my answer to add several options that work in Linux. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The below Bash code should move the files.  I don't know what you mean by "*execute in this folder the file 'executable.exe' infinitely*".  You may be able to use Cygwin's `/proc` filesystem to examine the memory usage of `executable.exe`.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f |
    while read FILE
    do
        set -- $(/bin/ls -l "$FILE")
        [ "$5" -lt 120000 -o "$5" -gt 200000 ] && mv "$FILE" folder
    done
echo "Files copied!"
if cd folder
then
    sh toto.sh
else
    echo "Failed to cd into folder!" >&2
fi
```

BTW, my numbers are not exactly 200 kilobytes and 120 kilobytes.  Feel free to do the math yourself (e.g., 200 * 1024 and 120 * 1024) to get exact byte counts.

Comment: I don't know how you could make so much sense about this post :D

Comment: Thanks Fran, your solution works fine for me, I need just to do one last thing : after copying all the file in the folder you called 'folder' I want to execute a file inside it called 'toto' using the command "sh toto.sh" how can I do this ?

Comment: @dotNET I've updated the script (above) to do that.